# Setting up 2 Wifi Routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

I want to make a wifi network like the condition below. (I) as the gate for internet access while (A) is for local network only. All the devices like computers or mobile phones are connected to (A) and Wifi router (A) should be independent from wifi router (I), even when wifi router (I) is disconnected or turned off, the local network should still work as usual.

I have tried making router (A) as repeater for router (I), but I cannot turn off router (I) as the result. I need help to make it works with the condition above.

I have TPlink WR840N as router (A) and TPlink MR3420 as router (I). I have a diagram but the forum wont allow me to upload it. Daisy Zhou helped me with the correct diagram on a post below.

Comment: If all devices are connected to router A, and it is providing basic network services like DHCP to the internal clients, and router I is connected to the Internet port of router A, then internal network functions of A should work regardless of whether router I is there or not. This is no different than if I turn off/disconnect the Internet from a single router, the internal network still functions, I just can't get to the internet. If I am misunderstanding, can you provide a simple diagram with IP's?

Comment: A diagram would make this question easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The WAN port is connected to the external network, and the LAN port is connected to the internal network.

1. I's WAN port is connected to the Internet LAN port to connect the wired network and A's WAN port.
2. I's WAN port is configured as an Internet LAN port, for example, the LAN port of I can be configured as 192.168.1.1.
3. The WAN port of A is connected to the LAN port of I. For example, the WAN port address of A is configured as 192.168.1.2, and then the LAN port address of A is configured to 192.168.2.1.

Note：

1. We need to change the LAN address of the A router, because the default tplink is 192.168.1.1, so we change it to 192.168.2.1.
2. The WAN port address of A need to be set as a static IP address.

The topology image is displayed as follows:

[image]

Comment: so I have to connect the WAN port of A Router to I Router LAN with ethernet cable? or can I also connect them wirelessly?

Comment: Yes, with ethernet cable.